# how to terminate a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, null-terminated

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string a;
cin>>a;
int len=a.length();
bool hit[256];
memset(hit,0,sizeof(hit));
hit[a[0]]=1;
int tail=1;
for(int i=1;i<len;i++)
{
    if(!hit[a[i]])
    {
        a[tail]=a[i];

    ++tail;
    hit[a[i]]=true;
}
}
a[tail]='\0';
cout<<" "<<a;
}
```

This program removes duplicates in strings. For example an input of `"aaaa"` will print only "a".

What I need to know is how to terminate the string in C++! It is not terminating with `'\0'`. I read some questions on stackoverflow that indicate the termination of a string in c++ doesn't use `'\0'`. I did not find how to terminate the strings instead. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Null-terminate a string is something you *won't* have to deal with with `std::string`. Firstly, every function that accepts `std::string` already knows the length and does not require `NULL` termination. Secondly, `std::string` has a `c_str()` wrapper that provides a `NULL`-terminated string for you, so you don't have to screw around with it. Just set the string to the length you want with `resize` and it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the size of the string by `string::resize`, no null-termination is needed:

```
a.resize(tail);
```

Answer (score 1):

For removing duplicates you can use `std::unique` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) is the description of the function. It will return "*An iterator to the element that follows the last element not removed*". So you can resize your string using `a.resize(i)` where `i` is the return value of `std::unique`.